# Obtener la cantidad de dígitos de un entero

Tags: c#

Mi duda es cómo puedo hacer para que cuando le pida la cédula me deba ingresar obligatoria mente 9 dígitos y no 2 o 3, etc.

```cs
try {
    Console.Write("\n"+"Ingrese cedula de identidad (Sin guiones ni puntos. Ej: 50389686");
    Console.Write("\n"+"Cedula : ");
    cedula = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    mensaje = mensaje +"La cedula no es un dato numerico\n";
}
```

Comment: cedula es un string?

Comment: es de tipo int cedula

Comment: Ok. Como string es mas facil fijarte cuanto mide ;)

Comment: si lo hago con un string como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 5):

Ya tienes varias respuestas interesantes te dejo una más usando Regex

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{9}$");

Console.WriteLine( rgx.IsMatch("154879054") );//9 numeros = TRUE
Console.WriteLine( rgx.IsMatch("15487905") );//8 numeros = FALSE
Console.WriteLine( rgx.IsMatch("15487905X") );//8 numeros 1 letra = FALSE
Console.WriteLine( rgx.IsMatch("X54879054") );//8 numeros 1 letra = FALSE
Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("᧙٧௯꘡६٩໖૫௫")); //Otros numeros = FALSE
```

Comment: La pregunta es en [tag:c#], no JavaScript. Además, si fuese JavaScript, no tiene sentido pasarle un objeto RegExp al constructor `RegExp()`.

Comment: Veo que lo editaste para que sea código de c#. No obstante, algo como `rgx.IsMatch("᧙٧௯꘡६٩໖૫௫")` [devolvería `True`](http://rextester.com/QUEP93868).

Comment: No hay gran diferencia , pero bueno ya lo edite para C#
¿Por qué no va a tener sentido?, de esa forma podras usar varias veces el mismo patron y opciones en caso de tenerlas

Comment: porque en JavaScript, sería directamente `var rgx = /^\d{9}$/;`. El [constructor `RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) se usa cuando se quiere generar un objeto regexp a partir de un string.

Comment: Ahora sí quedó bien. Gracias por considerar los comentarios. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Esto es una propiedad matemática. El [logaritmo decimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logaritmo_decimal) de un número devuelve la cantidad de dígitos (a la que hay que sumarle 1).

```cs
Math.Floor(Math.Log10(cedula) + 1);
```

De esta forma, se puede validar que tenga 9 dígitos:

```cs
int digitos = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(cedula) + 1);

if (digitos == 9)
{
    Console.WriteLine("La cédula es válida");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("La cédula debería tener 9 dígitos");
}
```

Comment: Supongo que lo que el OP requiere es validar la entrada a 9 dígitos y únicamente valores numéricos, aunque no logro comprender completamente tu respuesta...

Comment: @Flxtr completé el código para que quede más claro. No dudes en comentar si aún así no se entiende.

Comment: Un [tag:Regex] se adaptaría de una mejor maneja para validar la entrada a 9 números únicamente ;)

Comment: @Flxtr ya tiene un entero, no hay necesidad de convertir a string. Un regex sólo agregaría llamadas innecesarias y una biblioteca pesada para una tarea trivial, en mi opinión

Comment: Sí, puede ser una tarea pesada para este caso, aunque es suceptible de ingresar cualquier caracter. Si se llegara a ingresar una letra, [enviaría una excepción](http://rextester.com/XOKMZN19445)

Comment: @Flxtr eso es tal cual como el autor está buscando manipularlo. Ya está gestionando la excepción, y está preguntando cómo obtener a cantidad de dígitos de un entero. La respuesta apunta a atender eso precisamente.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @Mariano lo de math no lo conozco, podría reemplazarlo por algo mas básico?

Comment: @Francop esto son 2 funciones, log() y tomar la parte entera. Es la mejor forma de, dado un entero > 0, obtener la cantidad de dígitos. log(x) significa "10 elevado a qué número te da x".

Comment: Esto es realmente una forma muy rara de hacer las cosas y todavia tiene q haber convertido el string a entero primero, No es que sea basico  es una mala practica, la cedula tendra numeros pero es un string "012345678" falla con este metodo

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves el autor de la publicación aclaró que es un entero. Por favor le los comentarios previos

Comment: Sigues estando mal `(cedula>=100000000&&cedula<=999999999)` resuelve el problema. El logaritmo es una funcion mas costosa para algo tan sencillo, obscurece el codigo

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves voté +1 en tu respuesta. Pero son 2 formas diferentes de encarar el problema. En esta respuesta busco la forma de devolver la cantidad de dígitos. Es más costosa que tu comparación, pero no me arriesgaría a decir que el cálculo simple de un logaritmo sea de por sí costoso ni que obscuresca un código.

Answer (score 2):

A la hora de recoger el dato, lo tienes que recoger como un String, para poder calcular su longitud de una manera muy sencilla, llamando a su método length, una vez comprobado que la longitud es 9, sólo te queda llamar al método TryParse de la clase Int32. Yo lo haría así:

```
Console.Write("\n"+"Ingrese cedula de identidad (Sin guiones ni puntos. Ej: 50389686");
Console.Write("\n"+"Cedula : ");
cedula = Console.ReadLine();

if(cedula.length()!=9)
    mensaje = mensaje + "La cedula no tiene 9 caracteres\n"
}else{
    int resp = 0;
    if(Int32.TryParse(cedula, resp))  //Si lo puede convertir a entero
        Console.Write("El valor de la cedula es " + resp);
    else
        mensaje = mensaje +"La cedula no es un dato numerico\n";
}
```

Si quieres hacer algo con el valor pasado a entero deberás nombrarlo global al método o a la clase, dependiendo lo que quieras hacer. También puedes hacer primero la comprobación de que se puede pasar a un entero y luego ver su longitud, como he dicho antes, depende de lo que convenga.

Answer (score 2):

Si ya la tienes en un entero es asi como se comprueba  cedula>=100000000 &&cedula<=999999999

pero la cedula esta hecha de numeros pero matematicamente no vas a relizar ninguna operacion con ella lo mas probable

Para mi la forma mas normal es la de @Lato  o puedes usar LinQ ya q la expresion es muy sencilla

```
static bool validaCedula(string s){return s.Length > 7 && s.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');}
```

Quedaria asi

```
try {
    Console.Write("\n"+"Ingrese cedula de identidad (Sin guiones ni puntos. Ej: 50389686");
    Console.Write("\n"+"Cedula : ");
    string scedula = Console.ReadLine();
    if(!validaCedula(scedula)){
       //Lanzar el error de que no es valida la cedula

    }
    //Si todavia quiere usarla omo int
    cedula = Convert.ToInt32(scedula);
}
catch
{
    mensaje = mensaje +"La cedula no es un dato numerico\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un bucle do while que le repita la pregunta si no son 9 digitos

```js
bool numerico = false;

do {
  Console.Write("\n"+"Ingrese cedula de identidad (Sin guiones ni puntos. Ej: 50389686");
  Console.Write("\n"+"Cedula : ");
  cedula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  //Longitud del numero
  string cedula_string = cedula.ToString();
  int size = cedula_string.Lenght;
  if (size != 9) {
    Console.Write("Número no válido.);
  } else {
    numerico = true;

} while (numerico = false);
```

Pasas a cadena el entero, lees la cantidad de caracteres que tiene y si no tiene 9, indicas valor no válido y repite el bucle. Si no, si tiene 9 dígitos lee el número y sale del bucle. Puede que tenga algun fallo de escritura mi código.